# Sencha 1.1 Long DropBox List

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a droplist in sencha 1.1 with varying items.

It is showing unsual behaviour in iPad. When the list is having 3 items, it is displayed like following :

[image]

but when it is having more than 3 items, it is being displayed like following:

[image]

The list itself is overlapping the list-box border. This behavious is only been seen on iPad.

Is this a default behaviour or do I need to make some bug fix. If bug fix, then is their any iOS specific patch for sench to resolve this issue.

Kindly, don't suggest me upgrading my sencha.

**MODEL**

```
Ext.regModel('LinkSt', {
    idProperty: 'LinkID',
    fields: [{
        name: 'LinkID',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'LinkURL',
        type: 'string'
    }]
});
```

**STORE**

```
var LinkStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    id: 'LinkStore',
    model: 'LinkSt'
});
```

**VIEW**

```
var linkselectfield = {
            id: 'link',
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            name: 'BG-Color',
            label: 'Link To',
            labelWidth: '26%', //Changed to 100% to work with ms grid instead, divs are problematic in Win 8.
            cls: 'linkselectfield',
            store: LinkStore,
            displayField: 'LinkURL',
            valueField: 'LinkURL',
            itemTpl: '{text}',
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function (ele) {//Rahul ->22 jan
                    ele.fieldEl.dom.readOnly = true;
                },
                change: function () {
                    var islink = Ext.getCmp('link').getValue();


                    var sURL = islink; //LinkStore.getAt(LinkStore.find('LinkURL',islink)).get('LinkURL');



                    if (sURL == 'URL') {

                        Ext.getCmp('linkurl').setDisabled(false);
                        Ext.getCmp('linkurl').setValue("http://");
                    }
                    else {

                        Ext.getCmp('linkurl').setValue("");
                        Ext.getCmp('linkurl').setDisabled(true);
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        var linkrow = new Ext.Panel({
            cls: 'audiohbox',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox'
            },
            items: [linkselectfield, linkField]
        });
```

Thanx

Comment: we can add items in dropdown list dynamically..but the problem is that exceeding 3 items results in what is being displayed in image 2. Also, the same code is working absolutely perfect for other deices and browsers [Android, Windows, Chrome] @ThinkFloyd

Comment: even I am facing similar issues but its not consistent. Sometimes its on chrome and sometimes its on iPad.